# Issue with org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I am new to Spring-boot and hooking up my code to a database. Therefore I have been following a tutorial found [here](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2016/03/springboot-working-jdbctemplate.html). I have created a mostly blank database called `test` (though it does have a table called `users`).

The layout of `users` is shown below:

```
 mysql> describe users;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| emial | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Based on my relative inexperience with mySQL, Spring-boot, and databases what step(s) should take to get the above tutorial to work? I am likely making many silly beginners mistakes. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/Users/michaellayman/IdeaProjects/Work/JDBC%20Demo/SpringbootJdbcDemoApplication2/target/classes/schema.sql]: CREATE TABLE users ( id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(100) NOT NULL, email varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id) ); nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'users' already exists; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/Users/michaellayman/IdeaProjects/Work/JDBC%20Demo/SpringbootJdbcDemoApplication2/target/classes/schema.sql]: CREATE TABLE users ( id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(100) NOT NULL, email varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id) ); nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'users' already exists
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at edu.demo.SpringbootJdbcDemoApplication.main(SpringbootJdbcDemoApplication.java:9) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
```

**SpringbootJdbcDemoApplication.java**

```
package edu.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootJdbcDemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootJdbcDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**SpringbootJdbcDemoApplicationTests.java**

```
package edu.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.*;

@org.junit.runner.RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(SpringbootJdbcDemoApplication.class)
public class SpringbootJdbcDemoApplicationTests {
        @Autowired
        private UserRepository userRepository;

        @org.junit.Test
        public void findAllUsers() {
                List<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
                Assert.assertNotNull(users);
                Assert.assertTrue(!users.isEmpty());
        }

        @Test
        public void findUserById() {
                User user = userRepository.findUserById(1);
                Assert.assertNotNull(user);
        }

        @Test
        public void createUser() {
                User user = new User(0, "John", "john@gmail.com");
                User savedUser = userRepository.create(user);
                User newUser = userRepository.findUserById(savedUser.getId());
                Assert.assertNotNull(newUser);
                Assert.assertEquals("John", newUser.getName());
                Assert.assertEquals("john@gmail.com", newUser.getEmail());
        }
}
```

**User.java**

```
package edu.demo;

public class User{
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String email;

    public User(int number, String strName, String strEmail){
        id = number;
        name = strName;
        email = strEmail;
    }

    public User(){

    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
package edu.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreator;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.GeneratedKeyHolder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.KeyHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class UserRepository {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query("select * from users", new UserRowMapper());
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public User findUserById(int id){
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select * from users where id=?", new Object[]{id}, new UserRowMapper());
    }

    public User create(final User user){
        final String sql = "insert into users(name,email) values(?,?)";

        KeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
        jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
            @Override
            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                ps.setString(1, user.getName());
                ps.setString(2, user.getEmail());
                return ps;
            }
        }, holder);

        int newUserId = holder.getKey().intValue();
        user.setId(newUserId);
        return user;
    }
}

class UserRowMapper implements RowMapper<User>{
    @Override
    public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
        user.setName(rs.getString("name"));
        user.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
        return user;
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username= root
spring.datasource.password= password

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

**data.sql**

```
insert into users(id, name, email) values(1, 'Siva', 'siva@gmail.com');
insert into users(id, name, email) values(2, 'Prasad', 'parasad@gmail.com');
insert into users(id, name, email) values(3, 'Reddy', 'reddy@gmail.com');
```

**schema.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE  users
(
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  email varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you seek is in the stack trace of the exception.  You need to correct your schema.sql using AUTO_INCREMENT with an underscore.

This script is failing to initialise your database and is causing Spring to fail to initialise your dataSourceIntializer correctly.

You also need to check for typos as your UserRepository.create is using inset instead of insert.

Comment: Right. As @AmirRaminfar suggested, which I have changed. Though I still receive the same error. I have modified the OP to reflect those corrections. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you edited the exception trace to the most recent exception then it is still complaining AUTO INCREMENT with no underscore.  Check your edits and try again

Comment: Whoops, the stack trace is now updated. Though, as you can see, still the same error.

Comment: Check the first line of the trace. It says the users table already exists. Try using CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST users

Comment: I went and dropped the `users` table and now things are working. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in `schema.sql`. `AUTO INCREMENT` needs to be `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Also I noticed in `create(final User user)` you wrote `inset` instead of `insert`.

Comment: Making those changes results in the same error. Any other ideas?